# JAXB classes generation from XSD schema results in a strange package structure

Tags: java, maven, soap, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

With the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I generate classes from an XSD schema (let's say `entity.xsd`) placed in the `/src/main/resources`, the root element with namespace definition is on the example below:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:webpage="https://www.mywebpage.com"
    targetNamespace="https://www.mywebpage.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    ...
</xs:schema>
```

Upon `mvn clean install`, the generated structure in the `target/generated-sources/jaxb` is very odd:

- `target/generated-sources/jaxb`

  - `https`

    - `www_mywebpage`

      - `ObjectFactory.java`
      - `Entity.java`
      - `EntityDetailsRequest.java`
      - `EntityDetailsResponse.java`

I expected something like:

- `target/generated-sources/jaxb`

  - `com.mywebpage`

    - `ObjectFactory.java`
    - `Entity.java`
    - `EntityDetailsRequest.java`
    - `EntityDetailsResponse.java`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Why did you expect `com.mywebpage`? You didn't specify that anywhere. Perhaps if you explicitly specified `<packageName>` you'd get what you want. I mean, that's in the very first [example](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html) on the plugin documentation site.

Comment: @Andreas: I followed the following tutorial: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-soap-webservice-example/. The plugin should generate the package according to the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a mistake in the XSD schema. The `maven-jaxb2-plugin` doesn't recognise `https` but only `http`.

I changed:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:webpage="https://www.mywebpage.com"
    targetNamespace="https://www.mywebpage.com"
```

To:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:webpage="http://www.mywebpage.com"
    targetNamespace="http://www.mywebpage.com"
```

And the generated structure is as I expected and described in my question.